# Should I develop a separate express server, or handle all API calls in my next.js app?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, firebase, express, next.js

My website will perform CRUD operations and will work with MongoDB and Firebase storage+auth.

What are the reasons / advantages to developing a separate Express server instead of integrating everything in my next.js app?

As far as I have seen, it can all be done in my next.js app, but I still see many projects working with a separate server.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### Depends on what your app does and how you are hosting it.

Running Next.Js on a standard server will be of little difference whether you are using nextjs's /api or expressjs.

However if you are hosting on serverless (e.g. Vercel), I would recommend using a separate express server if you have alot of CRUD operations because the warming up of serverless is really bad user experience.

#### Build and Deployment

Next/JS - If you want to edit something on the backend, and push the changes, it will require you to build the entire JS app, and depending on how big is your app, it can take alot of time (especially if alot of static generated pages).

Express - If you running express separately, you can build and deploy front end and backend separately. It's time saving, and you can also better organise your codes frontend/backend.

#### Choice of deployment

I have a choice to take advantage of Vercel to host my frontend, with static generated pages and some server side generated pages (automatic scaling, caching, CDN etc), and host my backend with a separate cluster of servers.

**PS**: I moved from single Next.JS app to NextJs+Express

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit more about the warming up problem when hosting on serverless? I do plan on using vercel. I don't expect too many crud operations.

Comment: serverless functions takes time to "start up" on the first time it's called, during this time it's call 'warming up'. So it make take a few seconds before the first function can be executed. After the function is warmed up, it will continue to be available for a couple of minutes before it's shutdown. During this period, it will respond normally. If your page is not visited for a long period of time, the first visitor will see your page only after a few seconds (if it's SSR). You can google "serverless warm up"

Comment: This question is old but I want to know if it's best to call the Next.js server as a proxy to forward requests to my main backend server hosted somewhere else, or should I directly send requests to the backend server and skip Next.js entirely?

Comment: what kind of app is it? Is it just a blog? If you just need ssr pages etc u can just nextjs on it's own.

Answer (score 6):

I can think of a few things why they would have a different server from the one NextJS provides:

1. Familiarity with Express, Koa, etc. All [next-connect](https://github.com/hoangvvo/next-connect) helps with this
2. There is an already existing API in PHP, Express, Flask, etc.

Answer (score 5):

It is literally based on what you would want to do, the extra interactions with MongoDB & Firebase would be same on both the technologies, unless you want to isolate respective things separately, I don't see any harm in doing everything together on next.

Given that the idea of using next.js, as per my understanding would be to utilise server side rendering.

Answer (score 3):

I've been using Next.js with Typescript for quite a while now and I, as of now, have found one reason not to include `express.js` in my project. And the reason is **Vercel**.

Since I use Vercel for continuous deployment of my projects, and Vercel **Not supporting** any custom server as of there Docs [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server), I refrain from using Express or any other custom servers.

I didn't face any problem performing CRUD operations with MongoDB, can't say about firebase.

On Next.js Docs, I found these points to be considered:

1. A custom server can not be deployed on Vercel, the platform Next.js was made for.
2. A custom server will remove important performance optimizations, like serverless functions and **Automatic Static Optimization**.

But at the end of the day it very personal opinion weather to use a custom server or not. It might depend on a very specific use case you might be looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I try to keep it to just NextJS, but if I have to manage real-time data with Socket.io, I get a separate server because other than WebSockets, serverless functions can do everything else.