# Is there any problem by using custom server in nextjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, server, next.js

I want to use node-cron in nextjs. But, it only needs to initialize at the beginning of the server, and no need for recalling in every render. The one way I found it is by using a custom server. But, if I use the custom server, will it affect performance or is there any other issue with that?

Comment: I've an written an answer @ https://stackoverflow.com/a/67363418/2822041

Comment: Depends on a few factors, custom server has some caveats (see https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server), but should generally work fine most of the time. The question you should ask yourself is if it's really needed for your use case. Maybe you can initialize the cron job without a custom server, or maybe you can do that externally to your Next.js app.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I develop a separate express server, or handle all API calls in my next.js app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67358959/should-i-develop-a-separate-express-server-or-handle-all-api-calls-in-my-next-j)